# fatal error: fw_data_5517.i: No such file or directory #include "fw_data_5517.i"

Tags: android-kernel

```
In file included from /rom/tb8504/kernel/lenovo/msm8953/drivers/input/touchscreen/elan/elan_ts.c:26:0:
/rom/tb8504/kernel/lenovo/msm8953/drivers/input/touchscreen/elan/elan_ts.h:151:28: fatal error: fw_data_5517.i: No such file or directory
   #include "fw_data_5517.i"
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make[5]: *** [/rom/tb8504/kernel/lenovo/msm8953/scripts/Makefile.build:258: drivers/input/touchscreen/elan/elan_ts.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [/rom/tb8504/kernel/lenovo/msm8953/scripts/Makefile.build:402: drivers/input/touchscreen/elan] Error 2
```

Device tree: https://github.com/dazza5000/android_device_lenovo_TB8504

Vendor tree:= https://github.com/dazza5000/android_vendor_lenovo_TB8504

Kernel Source:=  https://github.com/dazza5000/android_kernel_lenovo_msm8953

ROM Source:= https://github.com/LineageOS/android

Haste or Dogbin URL:= https://del.dog/tyhubonura.txt

I tried multiple defconfigs and another kernel (https://github.com/redmidevs/android_kernel_xiaomi_msm8917), but also ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with a fw file that was missing.

I found the file on the lenovo site and copied it to the appropriate directory and then attempted to rebuild.

The lenovo source is here:

https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles/tb_8504f_8504x_s001030_191021_row_opensource.tar.gz

The firmware file contents can be found here:

https://github.com/dazza5000/android_kernel_lenovo_msm8953/blob/b1db30c463cbe429e6a750b6b2439519180e23a4/drivers/input/touchscreen/fw_data_5517.i